# parsing the page with Beautifulsoup html.parser returns empty response

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I wrote this little piece of code. It used to work fine, but now it returns an empty response. I have absolutely no idea why it doesn't work. I've changed my code many times and also used different parser like lxml to no avail. I'm new to coding in general so since there are no actual runtime errors I'm really confused. Can you please help me understand why `soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content, 'html.parser')` returns nothing?

Here is the little piece of code:

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

open_page = 'google.com'
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
manager = urllib3.PoolManager(1)
page_content = manager.urlopen('GET',open_page)
print(page_content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Comment: did you try to add an header? google may block your request since it seems suspicious.

Comment: @hansTheFranz This issue is with every website. I also tried to use HTTP only. But it didn't fix the problem. Also used it on a different system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might have switched from urllib2 to urllib3, which has a different interface. Your call to BeautifulSoup needs to be different:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content.data, 'html.parser')
```

which uses the `.data` member of the response object returned by `url open`.

Comment: That was beautiful. I was stuck with this for two days! Thank you so much. Funny thing is that I did try the .data member, but in the wrong way.